# Get the label beside my Macro inf a C-code

Tags: c, macros, label, line

I have a macro that I use to `goto', I want to let the macro know about the label.

Example:

```
#define MYMACRO((a),(b)) printf("I have arg: %s, %s with Label: %s at line %d", (a), (b), _GETLABEL_, __line__)    
mylabel: MYMACRO("a1","a2")
```

This should print:
I have arg: a1, a2 with Label: mylabel at line 4

Is it possible to implement *GETLABEL*? Will it be portable?

Thanks in advace,
Tarek

Answer (score 2):

Let the macro create the label:

```
#define MYMACRO(label, a, b) \
    label : printf("I have arg: %s, %s with Label: %s at line %d", \
    (a), (b), #label, __LINE__)
```

Then

```
MYMACRO(mylabel, "a1", "a2");
```

will evaluate to

```
mylabel : printf("I have arg: %s, %s with Label: %s at line %d", ("a1"), ("a2"), "mylabel", 42);
```